# Is it OK to name a MySQL index the same as the column it indexes?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, indexing

Is it considered bad form to give an index the same name as the column it is based on?

Like if you have a column named 'foo' and you want to create a normal index on it, would it be okay to name the index 'foo'? MySQL doesn't complain, but I am wondering what the pros and cons are.

Comment: It's okay to do so because MySQL uses indexes differently than column names and so they do not conflict. But it's best to follow a naming convention so that you can easily distinguish between the two, perhaps add a prefix to your indexes like 'id_' or 'idx_' or 'ix_'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The convention doesn't matter so much as that you are consistently using it.

That said, I prefix index names with "ind_"; Constraints get the "cns_" prefix.  In either case, the column name(s, if composite/covering).

Answer (score 10):

As a convention, index names should begin with the name of the table they depend on, like:-

Let the table name be "`USERS`", and the names of the fields be "`id`" & "`username`", for example. Then the index name could be "`IDX_USERS_ID_USERNAME`".

However, don't worry too much on the convention, as long as they are understandable by anybody who will access the database after some months, without your help.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Some databases (Oracle) have a character limit; table name shouldn't be necessary unless the same column name is in more than one table...

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with your point. I actually wanted to provide a very general example, with consideration for the JOINing of tables also. But my mistake of not mentioning it in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are not columns and index names are only for readability.  You can name them whatever you want.  If the index is on a single column then it makes sense to give it the same name as the column.